# Edit page structure

Tags: php, mysql

I have an edit form for **place**. Places can only be edited by agent who created "owner" entry.

link to edit page: */edit.php?owner=1&place=2*

**I. DATABASES:**

**Place owner information (db owner):**

```
ownerID(PK)       oAddress       oPhone       agentID
------------------------------------------------------ 
   1              street 15       0523541        500
```

**Place information (db place):**

```
placeID(PK)       pAddress       pPhone       ownerID
------------------------------------------------------ 
   1              street 24       0523541        500
```

**Image information (db images):**

```
imageID(PK)       URL             placeID
--------------------------------------------------- 
   1           image.jpg            5
```

**Country Database (database of countries for select field)**

**II. STRUCTURE (not actual PHP code):**

```
data from login session ->  $agentID

owner ID from url -> $ownerID

place ID from url -> $placeID

SELECT agentID, oAddress, oPhone FROM owner WHERE ownerID='$ownerID' ($oAgentID)

check if $oAgentID==$agentID (if agent is allowed to edit, if not exit code).

check if submit button is set (if yes -> include UPDATE code )

SELECT * FROM place WHERE placeID='$placeID'

SELECT * FROM countries

SELECT url FROM images WHERE placeID='$placeID'

<html>

<img>current place images preview</img>

<form>

text inputs, values filled with current database data
form submit

</form>
</html>
```

My question:

Is this structure good? I think there are too many selects from the database. I maybe could have joined the place table with owner table before the UPDATE process, but then the values would not be current.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do the images and the countries fit in in that structure? I can't see them being used anywhere.

Comment: If you're only performing a handful of queries on a page load, especially filtering for single records, it should be relatively fast.  I've ran websites where each page made around 70-80 queries per page load, and loaded in less than 0.1 seconds.  It's only a real performance problem if you're working with 1000's of records on the back-end and filtering search strings, etc.  The best thing of course is to profile the result and see if it's fast enough for your business case.  Always prefer maintainable, simple code that works over complex optimizations that may not be necessary.

Comment: @Truth as written, images are for previews of current place photos (<img>) and countries are for <select> dropdown menu.

Comment: @mellamokb thanks for your answer. I do only select single records (max 3 when selecting from images database), so there should be no problem. :))